# Installation Warning: Cannot convert string

Tags: install, build

I am installing emacs from source on Ubuntu machine. `make install` successfully installed it.

Now when I start emacs it is showing this warning

```
Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-courier-medium-r-*-*-*-120-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*" to type FontStruct
```

and emacs fonts looks like this

[image]

which is not as good as previous fonts

[image]

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Does this help? http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1896584

Comment: It removed warning message but fonts are not rendering properly.

Comment: Use `.Xdefaults` to set the font you like. I have [this](https://github.com/kaushalmodi/dotfiles/blob/master/.Xdefaults#L33).

Comment: Did you build with fontconfig support?

Comment: @lunaryorn No. I ran `build-dep emacs24` and started installing from source.